# How to use google analytics in typescript and access dataLayer

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, typescript, data-layers

I am trying to access GA's dataLayer in typescript code. (angular controller).

I want to achieve this 'normal' js code:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'LoginSuccess'
});
```

What I tried to do: (I've added the google analytics d.ts)

```
declare var dataLayer: GoogleAnalyticsCode;


//This fails:    
dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'LoginSuccess'
});

//This is OK with typescript but I'm not sure this is how it suppose to be in GA:
dataLayer.push(['event', 'LoginSuccess']);
```

If i declare the dataLayer as Array the push works fine as the original js code...

Is this how it should be achieved? or what is the best practice?

Comment: 5 years later it's still a problem >_<

Comment: @JethroLarson lol, so press like XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the docs (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide?hl=en) the following seems the right way

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event' : 'LoginSuccess'
});
```

This is a bug in [the definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/google.analytics/ga.d.ts). A PR with clear reasoning and further analysis would be appreciated

@)-'--

Comment: I'll think about it, but I can declare the dataLayer as Array of Object and it works fine, so not sure if there is a reason to call it a 'bug'

Comment: If it prevents *intended usage* of the API ... its a bug. But in the end its just opinions `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`